# JAX-RS response - remove invalid XML characters before read entity

Tags: java, xml, jax-rs, invalid-characters

Is there any possibility to remove invalid characters from XML response before trying to read entity?

```
Response searchResponse = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get();
/..
SearchOutput searchOutput = searchResponse.readEntity(SearchOutput.class);
```

This code works fine when XML is correct but fails when response contains invalid Unicode characters.

How to workaround that assuming I can't change these invalid data in a database?